# comparing records in two files for data changes

Tags: java, string, file, comparison

I have user details files which I get every month end.

File will have columns like id, f name, l name, address, phone, bus phone, hobbies, books

id is the unique key to identify an individual.

I need to maintain a database with information from this file.

Say in Jan the file had 100 users.
In Feb the file had 110 users. Means 10 new users.

So I will sort both the files on id and will now the new 10 users and will add them.

Issue is, I also want to check for changes to the existing ids as well.

So for id 3 in jan the address was xyz and in feb file it became pqr, I want to know it and update the database accordingly.

So -- Most easy as well as efficient way to compare records in two files (fixed format) for knowing data change in columns ?

One way I could think of is having checksum for each record in both files and comparing them to know of the changes. But want to know if this is the correct way or is there a better approach ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9766720/887235

Got answer through above question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have the FileUtils.contentEquals method (http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html). This will work well in cases where there is no time-based headers etc and the contents can be compared directly

Comment: Do you have a pointer to an example doing this? contentEquals will tell me whether differences are there or not which in my case will always be there. What I want to know is what are the differencts - whether new rows are added or some rows deleted or there are rows which are modified!

Comment: As far as I'm aware, FileUtils just does the compare. So it may not serve your purpose.

Comment: I have posted a new question which explains my issue in detail. If you are interested!

Comment: Please add the link to your comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Easy and simple solution would be to add a last update column and put a date/time stamp there. This would essentially be the same as the checksum, but would be human readable. Both ways would be efficient enough for how small the database is.

Comment: I do have control over changing the file format. So the solution you suggest is not feasible. :(

Comment: Computing the hash/checksum would be a perfectly acceptable way of comparing them to see if the records are different. However, you won't be able to resolve conflicting edits very well, but that might not be a problem.